# quotients of amenable groups are amenable

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, amenability

I want to proof that 
for a discrete group $G$ and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$ the following holds:

> $G$ and $H$ are amenable $\Rightarrow$ the quotient $G/H$ is amenable (using one of the definitions below).

**Def:** 1) A discrete group $G$ satisfies the Følner condition if for every finite subset $E\subseteq G$ and for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a non-empty finite set $F\subseteq G$ such that $$\max\limits_{s\in E}\frac{|F\triangle sF|}{|F|}<\epsilon,$$ where $F\triangle sF$ denotes the symmetric difference of the sets $F$ and $sF$.

2) A discrete group $G$ is called amenable if it satisfies the Følner condition.

**Def:** A discrete group $G$ is called amenable if there is a left invariant mean, i.e. there exists a state $\mu\in S(l^{\infty}(G))$ such that $\mu(g\cdot f)=\mu(f)$ for all $g\in G,\; f\in l^{\infty}(G)$ (where $g\cdot f(h)=f(g^{-1}h)$ for all $h\in H$).

I have seen a proof of this fact using other definitions of amenability, but I should know a proof of this fact with one of the above stated definitions.

And I only consider discrete groups from now (since I know a proof that these definitions are equivalent if $G$ is discrete).

Let $G$ be a amenable group and $H$ an normal amenable subgroup ($H$ is automatically amenable if $G$ is amenable since if you have a left invariant mean $\mu\in S(l^{\infty}(G))$ then you can construct a left invariant mean $\mu\circ \iota \in S(l^{\infty}(H))$, where $\iota :l^{\infty}(H)\to l^{\infty}(\bigsqcup_{i\in I} Hg_i)\; f\mapsto f_i$ with $f_i(hg_i)=f(h)$ for $h\in H$, $\bigsqcup_{i\in I} Hg_i=G$).

I want to contruct a left inavriant mean $\tau :l^{\infty}(G/H)\to\mathbb{C}$. However, I'm not sure how to define $\tau$. One of my attempts: Consider the canonical projection $\pi:G\to G/H$ and the induced map $\pi^*:l^{\infty}(G/H)\to l^{\infty}(G),\; \pi^*(f)=f\circ \pi$. Let $\mu \in S(l^{\infty}(G))$ be a left invariant mean and define $\tau (f)=\mu ((\pi^*)^{-1}(f))$. I'm not sure if this definition does make sense.. And I guess to define $\tau$ it is necessary that $H$ is amenable as well..

My question is: How to define $\tau$ correctly?

(A proof of this fact using the Følner condition is welcome as well)

Regards

Comment: You don't need to assume that $H$ is amenable. Any quotient of an amenable group is amenable. I think the proof using Følner sets is straightforward.

Comment: @DerekHolt Def1 should be correct. And thanks for pointing out that it isn't necessary to asume that $H$ is amenable. It confused me first that I did not need it in my attempts.

Comment: the maximum of the quotient runs over all $s\in E$.

Comment: Yes, OK, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that $\tau$ needs to be defined on functions $f \in l^\infty(G/H)$.  So, using your notation, we can try taking $\tau(f) = \mu(\pi^*(f))$.

Clearly $\tau$ is unital and contractive, so it's a state.  We just need to check that it's left invariant.  Note that $g \pi^*(f) = \pi^*(gH f)$, since $$g \pi^*(f)(h) = \pi^*(f)(g^{-1}h) = f(g^{-1}hH) = f(g^{-1}HhH) = \pi^*(gHf)(h).$$

Let $f \in l^\infty(G/H)$, $gH \in G/H$ (with $g \in G$).  Then we have: $$\tau(gHf) = \tau(f(g^{-1}H \cdot)) = \mu(\pi^*(f(g^{-1}H \cdot)))= \mu(g\pi^*(f)) = \mu(\pi^*(f)) = \tau(f),$$ so $\tau$ is left invariant.

So your intuition was right.  You just don't want an inverse in your definition of $\tau$.

Comment: As for the Følner sets, I suspect that you can take a finite set of cosets in $G/H$, take a collection of representatives, find a satisfactory Følner set in $G$ for those representatives, and then take the projection of your Følner sets.  That probably works.